# ASP.NET MVC Routing? // UrlParamter.Optional Vs Empty String

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-routing

What is the actual difference between these two routes ?

&

These two routes are the same?

```
//Route 1.
routes.MapRoute("SampleRounteOne" , "{controller}/{action}/{id}" , new {id = UrlParamter.Optional})

//Route 2.
routes.MapRoute("SampleRounteTwo" , "{controller}/{action}/{id}" , new {id = ""})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No!** These two routes are not the same.

```
//Route1
route.MapRoute("Route1" , "{controller}/{action}/{id}" , new { id = UrlParameter.Optional});
```

The same thing can also be acomplished by setting the *id* to be an empty string: { id : ""}

**for example:**

```
//Route 2.
routes.MapRoute("Route2" , "{controller}/{action}/{id}" , new {id = ""})
```

This seems a lot short/breif, so why not we use this ?

What is the difference?

First thing:

you asking that : These two routes are the same?

**No**! these two routes are not same.

Now Come to the point!

**What is the actual difference between these two routes?**

When we type URL parameters values are parsed out of the URL and put into a dictionary?

Now When we use UrlParameter.Optional as a default value and no value is supplied in the URL, Routing does'nt even add an entry to the dictionary. If the default value is set to an empty string, the route value dictionary will contain a value with the key "id" and the value as an empty string. In some cases, this distincition is important it lets you know the difference between the *id* not being specified, and it being specified but left empty.

Answer (score 2):

**Theoretically speaking:**

In `Route1` you have a parameter which is declared as `UrlParameter.Optional`, which, for instance, is *optional*.

In `Route2` your parameter is default set to `""`, which is an empty string.

**Practically speaking:**

On `Route1`, your parameter will be of `Nullable` so the default value is `null` when you're passing it to the controller.
So you will have this kind of implementation:

```
public void MyController(string? id)
{
    //dowork
}
```

On `Route2`, your parameter will be Non-`Nullable` type, which, for default, will be valued to `""` on your controller, an empty `string`.
Your controller will look like this in this situation:

```
public void MyController(string id = "")
{
    //dowork
}
```

Comment: It's unclear from the question whether or not C# 8 is acceptable in this case and since you're using Nullable reference types, I would suggest that you specify the pre-requisites for your answer to work (for this feature, C# 8 would be required.)